# Solar date timeline view

Tags: components, delphi-7, timeline, farsi, persian-calendar

I have to design a Solar date timeline (Persian) with Delphi 7 for some projects in advance,
I've found a JVtimeline in the JVCL component series,  suitable for my goal, which uses a Gregorian calendar and just separates months and years divisions. as I need all days, weeks, months and years divisions in Solar calendar format, I can not use it directly.
Please help me how I have to reach my required goal.

I tried JVCL JVtimeline component but not applicable for me